# How to hide the tab bar in roxterm?

Tags: terminal

In `roxterm` when I go to edit profile under `tab` I activate hide tabs but they are still appearing when I create a new tab or window. Any idea on how to hide tabs under roxterm ?

Answer (score 0):

1. goto `Preferences`
2. then `Edit current profile`
3. select `Appearance`
4. and uncheck `Always show tab bar (un-check for hiding)`